# Why program won't exit until std::async finishes?

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous

Consider this program:

```
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;

    auto f = std::async(std::launch::async,[&]
    {
        a = 1;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
        a = 2;
    });

    auto result = f.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    if (result == std::future_status::timeout)
    {
        printf("Function timedout ! %d\n", a);
    }
    else if(result == std::future_status::ready)
    {
        printf("Function finished ! %d\n", a);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works as expected except that program won't exit until asynchronous task finishes. Why ?

Comment: Are you saying that when you run this your output is "Function finished? Because I just ran this and got "Function timedout".

Comment: No, depending on how long your wait is, it might timeout or finish. What I'm asking is, if it times out, process still waits for it to finish. However, it seems that question posted by Jarod42 makes sense. Process waits because destructor of future object blocks.

Comment: In your specific case, there's a direct answer to "Why?", namely that a reference to `int a` is captured, and allowing `a` to be destroyed while the task is still using it would break the world (in C++ parlance, cause "undefined behavior").

Comment: Isn't task being destroyed as well ?